# Styled-components: Override component style inside a new component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to override the style of a component inside another component.

So, I have a component A, with some div's inside(Wrapper, Header).
In a new component, I am trying to override component A. Inside that override I want some new styling to the Header component. I know I can reference a component inside the same component but I can't find any info about referencing inside a new component.

```
// Component A
import React from "react";

export default ({
  className,
  title
}) => (
    <Wrapper className={className}>
      <Header>{title}</Header>
    </Wrapper>
  )
);

const Header = styled.h2`
  padding-left: 0;
`;

// Component B
import React from "react";

export default () => (
    <CustomA>
      /* content */
    </CustomA>
  )
);

const CustomA = styled(<A />)`
  ${Header} {
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
`;
```

I expect Header to be changed but I get "Header is not defined".

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of issues to address.

*You can follow along on CodeSandbox.*  [image: Edit so.answer.57203735]

### 1. Export `Header` component from `Component A`

You need to make `Header` component available outside `Component A` so that it can be referenced within `Component B`.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Header = styled.h2`
  padding-left: 0;
`;

export default ({ className = "", title }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    <Header>{title}</Header>
  </div>
);
```

### 2. Errors in `Component B`

There are three issues here.

1. You need to pass the component name, not the instance to `styled()` function.

Instead of `const CustomA = styled(<A />)` where `<A />` is an instance,
Do `const CustomA = styled(A)`.

2. You need to import `Header` component exported from `Component A`.
   Now you can reference is within `styled(A)` as ${Header}.

   ```
   import styled from "styled-components";

   import A, { Header } from "./CustomA";

   const CustomA = styled(A)`
     ${Header} {
       padding-left: 20px;
     }
   `;

   export default () => <CustomA title="Component B Content" />;
   ```
3. The last issue is that, you aren't passing the `title` (I also did `className = ""` in `Component A` to make it optional).

Comment: @HenrikFischerBjelland Glad it worked . Would you mark it as an answer to others can find the answer & there is no more replies needed?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to use `styled` like below:

```
const CustomA = styled(A)``;
```

instead of

```
const CustomA = styled(<A/>)``;
```

Secondly, try the following code:

```
const CustomA = styled(A)`
  h2{
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
const CustomA = styled(A)`
    padding-left: 20px;
`;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.